# Micronaut declarative client with base url per environment

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-client

I'd like to be able to use Micronaut's declarative client to hit an a different endpoint based on whether I'm in a local development environment vs a production environment.

I'm setting my client's base uri in `application.dev.yml`:

```
myserviceclient:
  baseUri: http://localhost:1080/endpoint
```

Reading the docs from Micronaut, they have the developer jumping through quite a few hoops to get a dynamic value piped into the actual client. They're actually quite confusing. So I've created a configuration like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(PREFIX)
class MyServiceClientConfig {

  companion object {
    const val PREFIX = "myserviceclient"
    const val BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1080/endpoint"
  }

  var baseUri: String? = null

  fun toMap(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val m = HashMap<String, Any>()
    if (baseUri != null) {
      m["baseUri"] = baseUri!!
    }

    return m
  }
}
```

But as you can see, that's not actually reading any values from `application.yml`, it's simply setting a const value as a static on the class. I'd like that `BASE_URL` value to be dynamic based on which environment I'm in.

To use this class, I've created a declarative client like this:

```
@Client(MyServiceClientConfig.BASE_URL)
interface MyServiceClient {

  @Post("/user/kfc")
  @Produces("application/json")
  fun sendUserKfc(transactionDto: TransactionDto)
}
```

The docs show an example where they're interpolating values from the config map that's built like this:

```
@Get("/api/\${bintray.apiversion}/repos/\${bintray.organization}/\${bintray.repository}/packages")
```

But how would I make this work in the `@Client()` annotation?

Nowhere in that example do they show how `bintray` is getting defined/injected/etc. This appears to be the same syntax that's used with the `@Value()` annotation. I've tried using that as well, but every value I try to use ends up being `null`.

This is very frustrating, but I'm sure I'm missing a key piece that will make this all work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm setting my client's base uri in application.dev.yml

You probably want `application-dev.yml`.

> But how would I make this work in the @Client() annotation?

You can put a config key in the `@Client` value using something like `@Client("${myserviceclient.baseUri}")`.

Comment: Yep. Also `run { systemProperty('micronaut.environments','dev') }` was required in my `build.gradle`. Once I added that, I could use `@Client("\${myserviceclient.baseUri}")` (The backslash is required due to Kotlin's string interpolation). Thank you!

Comment: FYI... The system property isn't really required, that is one way to do it though.  For example, you could also set the `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` operating system environment variable and have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url somewhere in your code use this:

```
@Value("${micronaut.http.services.occupancy.urls}")
private String occupancyUrl;
```